# Adding a diverter to an electric dryer into a basement not the home

Tags: basement, dryer, vent, diverter

I would like to  put a diverter on our dryer vent on our electric dryer in the basement and not in the home.
Has anyone ever done this to take advantage of the air that comes out of the dryer.

I see kits that you can attach to your dryer vent that are supposed to work.  Do they?

Most of the basement is very cold and I have some very large houseplants growing under lights that would benefit from the moisture. However I see from a lot of posts that the dryer throws out a lot of harmful lint as well as chemicals. The vent will be connected to a small dryer in the laundry room area of my basement where a dehumidifier is plugged in and running.

Would the dehumidifier take care of the extra moisture problem everyone is speaking about?

Comment: An electric dryer does not exhaust any "chemicals", only heat and moisture from the drying clothes.

Comment: As long as you can keep the humidity under control, so you don't get mold/mildew, you should be OK, but regular maintenance to remove lint will be important.

Comment: The dryer vent stream contains lint in sufficient amounts to build up in the dryer vent over time. I would not vent this into the living space.

Comment: @AlaskaMan There will be some chemicals coming out of the detergent that didn't get entirely washed away... the main problem is this is a lot more moisture than OP thinks it is, and it will cause condensation since it'll be a *bolles* of moisture arriving much faster than the dehumidifier can get rid of it.

Comment: The basement will end up smelling much worse than the detergent aisle at the supermarket. If the OP is willing to take that, there probably nothing particularly _harmful_ (at least not known yet) in that, it's just really, really annoying.

Comment: 1. Much worse than the chemical smell of detergent is the incredible *stink* of most fabric softeners. 2. High humidity of exhaust can condense inside walls, causing rot or even ice buildup, and ruining thermal insulation. 3. Lint buildup, even with a lint filter, can trigger allergies (or white lung disease, if carried to extreme). Yes, this is pretty much a summary of other comments, with which I agree.

Comment: I purchased a home in Ohio that had one of these the walls of the basement were dripping wet (we got a good price reduction on the property for this). I removed the diverter and we installed a dehumidifier no more wet walls, after painting the basement floor a year later there was not much moisture being removed by the dehumidifier. We did not notice lint in the dryer area but the moisture was an issue. Some moisture was coming through the slab but not as much as the heat diverter was pumping in. I don’t remember a smell other than dampness but that was prior to heavily perfumed dryer sheets.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve used an exchange in my home for year only when it gets cold.  Dryer goes into the basement which is about 2000sq ft in size.  The exchange closes off the air to the outside and has a screen to capture lint into the basement. I have not noticed an excessive moisture in the basement, The fragrance was noticeably pleasant from the fabric softener sheets in the basement and was definitely a warmer temperature. It’s suggested to clean out the trap in the spring and any excess lint that may have gotten pass.